# Autoincrement in liquibase

Tags: java, postgresql, liquibase

How do i set the autoincrement property using 'startWith' on a column in PostgreSQL using liquibase??

For some reason it always starts from 1. I tried using a custom sequence but that didn't help either.

```
<column autoIncrement="true" startWith="100" name="id" type="bigint">
```

That's my current column definition which does not work.

EDIT:

I want to import data from csv using liquibase. I tried the following:

```
<changeSet author="author" id="createSequence">
    <createSequence
                    incrementBy="1"
                    sequenceName="mytable_id_seq"
                    startValue="1000"/>
    </changeSet>
</changeSet>


<changeSet author="author" id="1-mytable">
    <createTable tableName="mytable">
        <column name="id" type="BIGSERIAL" defaultValueComputed="nextval('mytable_id_seq')">
              <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="mytable_pkey"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>

    <loadData encoding="UTF-8"
              file="liquibase/data/mytable.csv"
              separator=","
              tableName="mytable">
    </loadData>
</changeSet>
```

If i try this I receive the following error 'currval of sequence "table_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session' and I think that it uses the sequence from the public schema instead of what i have set to liquibase.

2. Another thing i tried was to update it manually:

ALTER SEQUENCE mytable_id_seq restart with 100;

In this case the sequence used was the one from the public schema, but i want to use the schema set to liquibase

Comment: pay attention on liquibase version [bigserial columns not created as auto-increment](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3494)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using bigserial which is an autoincrementing bigint specific to postgres use bigint if you are going to be setting up your own increment and sequence.
"The data types smallserial, serial and bigserial are not true types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns (similar to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some other databases). In the current implementation, specifying:"

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname SERIAL
);
```

is the same as

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq AS integer;
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
);
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
```

From here

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-numeric.html