# liquibase doesn't create autoIncrement column on Oracle DB 12c

Tags: oracle, null, liquibase

So I am using liquibase version 3.8.5 on an Oracle Database 12c. What I want to do is create a table in this way:

```
<createTable tableName="a_table">
    <column name="id" type="int" autoIncrement="true">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
    </column>
    <column name="name" type="nvarchar(255)">
        <constraints nullable="false" />
    </column>
    <column name="value" type="nvarchar(255)">
        <constraints nullable="false" />
    </column>
</createTable>
```

After creation of the table, I am trying to fill it in this way:

```
<changeSet id="change_set" author="author"
    context="a_context">
    <insert tableName="a_table">
        <column name="name" value="NAME1" />
        <column name="value"
            value="VALUE1" />
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

It doesn't even seem to be able to create an autoIncrement table. What could be the issue?
The error I'm getting is:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Migration failed for change set path/to/my.xml::change_set::author:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("XXX"."A_TABLE"."ID")
[Failed SQL: (1400) INSERT INTO XXX.a_table (name, value) VALUES ('NAME1', 'VALUE1')]
```

I've searched through the internet but couldn't find anything. The Database is of version 12c and creating this table by hand using the direct sql code and IDENTITY with the same insert sql does work.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
After looking more into it, liquibase doesn't seem to be able to transfer the code into Oracle sql correctly. This is the INFO about the creation of the table:

```
[INFO ] 2020-02-03 12:12:11.650 [localhost-startStop-1] l.e.j.JdbcExecutor:42 - CREATE TABLE XXX.a_table (id INTEGER NOT NULL, name NVARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL, value NVARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_A_TABLE PRIMARY KEY (id))
[INFO ] 2020-02-03 12:12:11.713 [localhost-startStop-1] l.c.ChangeSet:42 - Table a_table created
```

Comment: Add a name for the autoincrement sequence and add in your insert `id = select nextVal(YOUR_SEQUENCE) from dual` (or something like that).

Comment: By the way, it's a bad idea to let Liquibase decide the name or your sequences.

Comment: How do I name a sequence and where exactly do I need to put this in my insert? I'm sorry I am not that knowledgeable in liquibase

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948103/autoincrement-in-liquibase

Comment: Maybe https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/index.html

Comment: I edited the question since I got new insights

Comment: What's your Liquibase conf ?

Comment: Related: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2591

Comment: @Zorglube what config do you mean? How I included the liquibase dependency in my pom.xml?

Comment: No, the config you setted up to tell Liquibase what are the characteristics of your BDD.

Comment: I don't think I have one. I added my database connection via context.xml and load it from there as  <Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource" name="jdbc/OracleDB"... and so on. Can I force liquibase to run in 12c compatibility mode?

Comment: Maybe liquibase.org/documentation/index.html

Comment: @Zorglube - *"it's a bad idea to let Liquibase decide the name or your sequences"* that may be so, but Oracle doesn't allows to explicitly name the sequences used by identity columns.

Comment: @APC Yep, you're right.